# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference :KOTLIN

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, listview

I am getting this from Logcat

2022-01-07 20:27:46.539 14327-14327/com.example.donedoobnew2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.donedoobnew2, PID: 14327
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
at com.example.donedoobnew2.Fragments.FragmentMinistries.onCreateView(FragmentMinisteries.kt:29)

FragmentMinistries.kt

```
class FragmentMinistries : Fragment() {
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
): View? {

    val customListData = ArrayList<CList>()
    val customList = CListAdapter(this.requireContext(), customListData)

    customListData.add(CList(R.drawable.ic_call, "First"))
    customListData.add(CList(R.drawable.ic_call, "Second"))
    customListData.add(CList(R.drawable.ic_call, "Third"))

    lv_donedoob_ministries.adapter = customList

    return LayoutInflater.from(container?.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.fragment_ministeries, container, false)
}

}
```

CListAdapter.kt

```
class CListAdapter(private val getContext: Context, private val customListItem: ArrayList<CList>) :
ArrayAdapter<CList>(getContext, 0, customListItem) {

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    var listLayout = convertView
    var holder: ViewHolder

    if (listLayout == null) {
        val inflateList = (getContext as Activity).layoutInflater
        listLayout = inflateList.inflate(R.layout.item_cardview_donedoob, parent, false)

        holder = ViewHolder()
        holder.mTextView = listLayout!!.findViewById(R.id.tv_card_donedoob)
        holder.mImageListView = listLayout.findViewById(R.id.iv_card_donedoob)

        listLayout.tag = holder
    } else {
        holder = listLayout.tag as ViewHolder
    }

    val listItem = customListItem[position]
    holder.mImageListView!!.setImageResource(listItem.mCListImage)
    holder.mTextView!!.text = listItem.mCListText


    return listLayout
}

class ViewHolder {
    internal var mImageListView: ImageView? = null
    internal var mTextView: TextView? = null
}
```

}

CList.kt

```
class CList(
var mCListImage: Int,
var mCListText: String,
)
```

fragment_ministries.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/gray"
tools:context=".Fragments.FragmentMinistries">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_donedoob_ministries"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:divider="@color/gray"
    android:padding="20dp">

</ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

item_listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/round_buttons"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_card_donedoob"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_my_documents" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_card_donedoob"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ministry og edu"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access ListView before inflating fragment view.

```
class FragmentMinistries : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View? {

        val customListData = ArrayList<CList>()
        val customList = CListAdapter(this.requireContext(), customListData)

        customListData.add(CList(R.drawable.ic_call, "First"))
        customListData.add(CList(R.drawable.ic_call, "Second"))
        customListData.add(CList(R.drawable.ic_call, "Third"))
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(container?.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_ministeries, container, false)

        view.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.lv_donedoob_ministries).adapter = customList

        return view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
lv_donedoob_ministries.adapter = customList

return LayoutInflater.from(container?.context)
    .inflate(R.layout.fragment_ministeries, container, false)
```

You are trying to set the adapter on the `ListView` (lv_donedoob_ministries) **before** you inflate the layout. You need to inflate the layout **first** before trying to set the adapter on it.

Comment: Thank you! I just needed to put all code in onViewCreated instead of onCreateView.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve the problem. If my answer was helpful you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. This will remove the question from the list of open questions and may help someone else who has a similar problem in the future!